# Calling several .exe-files in parallel from a Windows bat-file and piping the results to a common file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, parallel-processing, pipe

I would like to have a standard Windows .bat-file calling 3 instances of an .exe-file in parallel and pipe the result to a common text-file. Pseudo-code:

```
SET PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE=%~dp0"All Devices Contents.txt"

echo Device on COM1 returned the following: >  %PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE%
start /b  ReadFromComPortDevice.exe  COM1   >> %PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE%
echo Device on COM2 returned the following: >> %PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE%
start /b  ReadFromComPortDevice.exe  COM2   >> %PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE%
echo Device on COM3 returned the following: >> %PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE%
start /b  ReadFromComPortDevice.exe  COM3   >> %PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE%
```

Obviously, the above will create file access errors because the file will already be used by the first process. Does anybody know a workaround?

Comment: I would let every started process to write to its own dedicated temporary file, then I would collect their contents into the target output file as soon as all the sub-processes are finished…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest approach would to be to redirect the output of the batch file as a whole to the specified file:

```bat
@Echo off & CD /D "%~dp0"

If not defined _ (
 Set _=_
 Prompt $_
 Start /B "" "%~f0" >"All Devices Contents.txt"
 (Prompt )
 Exit /B
)

echo Device on COM1 returned the following:
start /b  ReadFromComPortDevice.exe  COM1
echo Device on COM2 returned the following:
start /b  ReadFromComPortDevice.exe  COM2
echo Device on COM3 returned the following:
start /b  ReadFromComPortDevice.exe  COM3

Set "_="
Goto :Eof
```

Comment: This obviously prevents file access conflicts, but the written data are not going to be ordered…

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to place the contents in the correct order:

```
echo Device on COM1 returned the following: >   TempCom1.txt
start /b  ReadFromComPortDevice.exe  COM1   >>  TempCom1.txt
echo Device on COM2 returned the following: >   TempCom2.txt
start /b  ReadFromComPortDevice.exe  COM2   >>  TempCom2.txt
echo Device on COM3 returned the following: >   TempCom3.txt
start /b  ReadFromComPortDevice.exe  COM3   >>  TempCom3.txt

call:waitForFileUnlocked TempCom1.txt
call:waitForFileUnlocked TempCom2.txt
call:waitForFileUnlocked TempCom3.txt

copy TempCom1.txt+TempCom2.txt+TempCom3.txt    "All Devices Contents.txt"

call:waitForFileUnlocked TempCom1.txt
call:waitForFileUnlocked TempCom2.txt
call:waitForFileUnlocked TempCom3.txt

del "TempCom1.txt"
del "TempCom2.txt"
del "TempCom3.txt"

pause

:waitForFileUnlocked
@echo off
:Wait
2>nul (
  >>%~1 echo off
) && (echo ) || goto :Wait
goto:eof
```